# Python ImportError: No module named

Tags: python, django

I try to run django project, which has this kind of structure: 2 apps in one project:

projectx

```
├──apps
│  ├── app1
|  |    ├── __init__.py
|  |    └── ...
│  └── app2
|       ├── __init__.py
|       └── ...
├──project
│  ├── settings.py
│  ├── urls.py
│  ├── __init__.py
|  └── ...
├── manage.py
└── ...
```

It has two apps in one project. Well, while running
    `python manage.py runserver` I get `ImportError: No module named apps`

`$ echo $PYTHONPATH`  gives
/home/alexander/Work/projectx

Django version 1.9.8

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...

'apps.app1',
'apps.app2'
]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add `__init__.py` inside your `apps` directory

```
    ├──apps
    ├──__init__.py
    │  ├── app1
    |  |    ├── __init__.py
    |  |    └── ...
    │  └── app2
    |       ├── __init__.py
    |       └── ...
```